# python remove last comma

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have some thing like this in output.txt file

```
Service1:Aborted
Service2:failed
Service3:failed
Service4:Aborted
Service5:failed
```

output in 2nd file(output2.txt) :

```
 Service1        Service2   Servive3   Service4     Service5
 Aborted         failed     failed     Aborted      failed
```

Would like to remove the last comma in the line.

Code I am trying:

```
    file=open('output.txt','r')
    target=open('output2.txt','w')
    for line in file.readlines():
          line=line.strip()
          parts=line.split(":")
          for part in parts:
               var2=part.strip()+","
          target.write(var2.rstrip(','))        # Not working
   target.close()
```

Comment: But you realize the indentation of `target.write(var2.rstrip(','))` is outside the for loop, right?

Comment: instead of the loop you could do `','.join(parts)`

Comment: Remove the last comma in the line, `var2[:-1]`

Comment: yes,  target.write(var2.rstrip(',')) is for the inner loop @MosesKoledoye

Answer (score 0):

Use a list and append the items to it. Accessing parts[-1] returns the last item from the splitted parts. Then use `join()` to put the commas in between all collected states:

```
states = []
for line in file.readlines():
    parts=line.strip().split(':')
    states.append(parts[-1])
print(','.join(states))
```

Comment: i have used rstrip() , its not wrking for some reason, although will keep trying. Thank you

Comment: I think it is because your control flow is not right. Please simplify your example. Why are you also splitting on a colon, and what does that have to do with the minimal code sample you need for your question?

Comment: Consider the string 'a, b, a, s, something.' In this case, we would not strip the final comma after the 's'. The question was not to remove trailing commas, but to remove the LAST comma in the string.

Comment: yes you were right, I have edited my question  @MichielB

Comment: Ah! Now I modified the answer based on this new input. Please check if it works for you.

Comment: yeah it works, Will try and remove the leading spaces. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This makes the output you originally requested:

```
file=open('output.txt','r')
target=open('output2.txt','w')
states = [line.strip().split(':')[-1] for line in file.readlines()]
target.write(','.join(states))
target.close()
```

That is, the output of this code is:

```
Aborted,failed,failed,Aborted,failed
```

For a table view, assuming the tabbed output will line up, this code:

```
file=open('output.txt','r')
target=open('output2.txt','w')
states, titles = [], []
for line in file.readlines():
    title, state = line.split(':')
    titles.append(title)
    states.append(state)
target.write('\t'.join(titles))
target.write('\n')
target.write('\t'.join(states))
target.close()
```

will produce the requested table view (note there are no commas in this output):

```
Service1        Service2   Servive3   Service4     Service5
Aborted         failed     failed     Aborted      failed
```

If you want to control alignment more precisely, you'll need to apply formatting, such as measuring the maximum width of text in each column and then using that as a formatting specifier.

Comment: Is there some way I can get the table view, like I just edited my required output?? @BarryPye

Comment: you might have asked this as a new question since your expected output is different (has no commas at all)